# How to switch between In-App-Purchase subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, switching

I have an app in App Store using In-App Purchase with non consumable type. Last week my client wanted to switch the In-App Purchase type from Non-consumable to Non-renewable subscription (user have to manually renew for each month). I have searched in Google and cannot find any solution. So, ccould anyone help,

1. How to switch between these types?
2. What are the changes need to be done in App Store connect page and my project side?
3. How to notify the users those who are purchased the products already with non-cosumable type?